# use first three digits of string to loop and group elements in output

Tags: loops, xslt, select, xslt-grouping

In the following xml the first three digits of "number"can be used to group "number" elements in resulted output. However I have no Idea how ? 
Please see the input XML and my desired output bellow

Input
[see the input and the desired output][1]

```
<data>
<InputElemenmts>
    <Element11>
        <key>73004</key>
        <number>001001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>7300465</key>
        <number>002001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730046</key>
        <number>003001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730046</key>
        <number>003002</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730046</key>
        <number>003003</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730049</key>
        <number>004001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730046</key>
        <number>005001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730040</key>
        <number>006001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730040</key>
        <number>006002</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730041</key>
        <number>007001</number>
    </Element11>
    <Element11>
        <key>730042</key>
        <number>008001</number>
    </Element11>
</InputElemenmts>
<OutputElemenmts>
    <result>
        <key>7300462</key>
        <number>001001</number>
    </result>
    <result>
        <key>7300465</key>
        <number>002001</number>
    </result>
    <result>
        <key>73004</key>
        <Element>
            <number>003001</number>
            <number>003002</number>
            <number>003003</number>
        </Element>
    </result>
    <result>
        <key>730049</key>
        <number>004001</number>
    </result>
    <result>
        <key>730046</key>
        <number>005001</number>
    </result>
    <result>
        <key>730040</key>
        <Element>
            <number>006001</number>
            <number>006002</number>
        </Element>
    </result>
    <result>
        <key>730041</key>
        <number>007001</number>
    </result>
    <result>
        <key>730042</key>
        <number>008001</number>
    </result>
</OutputElemenmts>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) We are not a code writing service. What have you tried and where is the problem in your code? Edit your question to show your effort please.

Comment: Hi Stefani - Unfortunatelly I have not did a lot because I have no idea how to do  ! When I had any idea, I were not here ! I tried with a for-each loop but I see I am far from the solution and is nothing to post it   :(

Comment: Is' nt clear enough what I want ?

Comment: For me it's clear, you want someone to do your job...sorry but you misunderstand SO

Comment: I think you had a bad day  :)  Wha avoid somebody withoult my own code to say in an example he has an idea, it looks like following.... ?

Comment: Maybe ... but if you prefer discussing over showing your xsl:for-each ... We all started by showing code other might have laughed about and sometimes still do. There is nothing wrong with that. xsl is a bit different language and someone can explain how one can put the thoughts into the right direction when seeing where you started. And your task already involves grouping, a bit advanced feature. BTW, I don't recognize where you use the "first three digits" for grouping in your output, it groups all different input keys?

Comment: @henry Grouping is probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Please do a search first - then ask a specific question if you run into problems. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I've understood but probably not what you wanted??

```
<!-- find the last of Element11 with any key -->
    <xsl:template match="Element11[not(following::Element11[key = current()/key])]">
       <result>
        <key><xsl:value-of select="key"/></key>
        <xsl:choose>
         <!-- are there more than one with this key? -->
         <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::Element11[key = current()/key]">
           <!-- if yes it seems you want an Element wrapper -->
           <Element>
             <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::Element11[key = current()/key]/number">
                <number><xsl:value-of select="."/></number>
             </xsl:for-each>
             <!-- the current one -->
             <number><xsl:value-of select="number"/></number>
           </Element>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
             <!-- only the current one -->
             <number><xsl:value-of select="number"/></number>
         </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
       </result>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Element11"/>
```